# ALB throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I'm trying to use ALB to distribute traffic to my instances. Then I use Route53 to map my root domain (example.com) and (www.example.com). Both use ALIAS to the Load balancer target.

Root domain works perfectly, but not with the www. Every time I tried to visit www.example.com, it will always throw ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. I wonder if it's caused by the ALB or the NGINX configuration behind the ALB?

I checked CloudWatch Monitoring for the Load balancer, but there's no HTTP error, and no error form NGINX / the app. Is the problem really caused by the Load Balancer? Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Is the ALB set to listen to both requests (root and www), does the ACM certificate support both, is NGINX configured to listen to both? If the root works but www doesn’t, could you just redirect www to root and that’d solve your issue?

Comment: Yea. I just found out that I only put listener on port 443 HTTPS. I solved the problem by adding listener on port 80 HTTP to redirect to port 443 HTTPS. Thanks!